# Login to my website fails after sometime

Tags: php, authentication

I have been utilizing this forum to take help in creating my first PHP website. I have most of the things up and running, but am facing an issue with my login.
If a new user signs up and login to the website, it works perfectly fine, but if I open the login database even once or if I view the list of users in the admin panel, all the previous user login fails and no one can login with those credentials again even when they are still present in the database. Any help?
Below is my login form code:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="1" width="100%">
        <form action="user.php" method="post">
        <tr>
           <td><label for="u_name">Your Email-id:</label></td>
           <td><input type="text"name="u_name" id="u_name" placeholder="Enter email-id" required="required"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td><label for="u_password">Password:</label></td>
           <td><input type="password" name="u_password" id="u_password" placeholder="Enter password" required="required"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="sub" value="login"/></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
     </body>
</html>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['sub']))
{
    $u_name=$_POST['u_name'];
    $u_password=$_POST['u_password'];
    include ("connection.php");
    $w="select * from signup";
    $b=mysql_query($w) or die(mysql_error()."in query $w");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($b))
    {
     $a=$row['email_id'];
     $u=$row['password'];
    }
if ($u_name==$a && $u_password==$u)
{
    $_SESSION['loggedin']=true;
    $_SESSION['user_email']=$_POST['u_name'];
    $_SESSION['user_pass']=$_POST['u_password'];
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=homepage.php">';
}
else
{
    echo "Your username or password is incorrect.Please try again";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: That sounds like a very interesting issue. Do you any code that you can share?

Comment: Have updated the code in the question.

Comment: its a bad practise to store password in session

Comment: Good to hear that you're working on your 1st PHP website. I suggest that you go through a few more tutorials 1. Don't use mysql_* functions. (They have been deprecated) 2. Try not to use tables in your HTML design. Replace them with divs.

Comment: @chiragode how should I verify the password on other pages if I do not store it in SESSION?

Comment: @ErdemEce I have stated the error in the question

Comment: Once a user has successfully logged in, you don't have to verify the password on all subsequent pages.

Comment: @om_deshpande Thank you for your suggestions.. However I am unable to handle divs at the moment. Content I put in divs almost always run out of the scope of the divs. Would re-design my website once the basic functionality is properly achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['sub']))
{
    $u_name=$_POST['u_name'];
    $u_password=$_POST['u_password'];
    include ("connection.php");
    $w="select * from signup where email_id = '$u_name' AND password = '$u_password'";
    $b=mysql_query($w) or die(mysql_error()."in query $w");
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($b);
    if($num_rows > 0)
    {
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($b);
        $_SESSION['loggedin']=true;
        $_SESSION['user_email']=$_POST['u_name'];
        $_SESSION['user_pass']=$_POST['u_password'];
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=homepage.php">';
    }
    else
    {
         echo "Your username or password is incorrect.Please try again";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: This seems fine, but can anyone suggest what the problem is in my code?

Comment: The problem with your code is that u check the input password against the LAST record in your database, which is not the correct user!
U need to use a `WHERE` statement

Comment: @user2801699 i believe it was your query

Comment: Also... don't store passwords in `plaintext`. It wants me to weep :'-(

Comment: MD5 is outdated ! Please refer to [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php). If u don't have PHP5.5 U can use [ircmaxell/password_hash](https://packagist.org/packages/ircmaxell/password-compat)

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal your code worked.. thank you.. 
Yes, it was my query and I was asking why the code was producing an error.. Thanks DarkBee for the answer..
Will you please also tell me where did I stated (in the code) that I have to scan the last record?? Doesn't the while() statement searches the whole database?

Comment: Yup. You should first salt and then hash your password before storing them in your database.

Comment: @DarkBee Got it.. Thank you.. Would anyone explain password hashing a bit more? Or give a code example of that?

Comment: @user2801699 [password FAQ](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php), best way is to use password_hash. If you have PHP5.3.7+ installed and <PHP5.5 u can use the library of ircmaxell. See link ^